# How do I apply different aligning options in different columns in a table?

Tags: tables, arrays, columns, alignment, cell

I'm trying to figure out how I get different aligning for different columns in my table.

I want the first and second column to be left-aligned and to the top of each cell (in case it turns out that the cell is vertically stretched in order to fit the text in the second column). Subsequently, I want the text in the 3rd to 7th column to be centered both horizontally and vertically. In fact, I want to insert different sized bullets in these cells in order to rank the relevance of each principle that is listed in the second column to the 4 categories in the 3rd to 7th column.

Currently, this is the closest I got:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\newcommand{\sdot}{\raisebox{0.25ex}{\large{$\bullet$}}\normalsize}
\newcommand{\mdot}{\raisebox{0.125ex}{\LARGE{$\bullet$}}\normalsize}
\newcommand{\ldot}{\Huge{$\bullet$}\normalsize}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Key principles rated against the four recycling strategies}
\label{tab:test}
\begin{tabular}{@{}m{0.2cm}m{6.6cm}M{1.4cm}M{2.3cm}M{1.5cm}M{1.6cm}@{}}
\toprule
 &
  Principle &
  Material recycling &
  Component remanufacture &
  Component reuse &
  Building relocation \\ \midrule
1.        & Use recycled and recyclable materials                                       & \ldot & \ldot & \sdot & \sdot \\
2.        & Minimise the number of different types of material Minimise the number of different types of material Minimise the number of different types of material                          & \ldot & TEXT & \sdot & text \\
3.        & Use recycled and recyclable materials                                       & \ldot & \ldot & \sdot & \sdot \\
4.        & Minimise the number of different types of material                          & \ldot & TEXT & \sdot & text \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

And it looks like this for me:

[image: NB: don't bother the alignment of the table itself on the page, since actually I'm using a documentclass that is created by my university]

So, currently the only column that I'm not satisfied with is the first column, since I want the numbers to be vertically aligned to the top of the cell it's in. I tried configurations with combinations of p{...}, m{...}, P{...} and M{...}, but nothing seems to work.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a customized enumerate and place number and text in the same cell:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\newcommand{\sdot}{\raisebox{0.25ex}{\large{$\bullet$}}\normalsize}
\newcommand{\mdot}{\raisebox{0.125ex}{\LARGE{$\bullet$}}\normalsize}
\newcommand{\ldot}{\Huge{$\bullet$}\normalsize}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabenum}{enumerate}{1}

\setlist[tabenum,1]{label*=\arabic*.,leftmargin=*,nosep,leftmargin=*,after=\vspace{-0.75\baselineskip}}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Key principles rated against the four recycling strategies}
\label{tab:test}
\begin{tabular}{@{}m{6.6cm}M{1.4cm}M{2.3cm}M{1.5cm}M{1.6cm}@{}}
\toprule
  Principle &
  Material recycling &
  Component remanufacture &
  Component reuse &
  Building relocation \\ \midrule
         \begin{tabenum}[series=tab]\item Use recycled and recyclable materials \end{tabenum}                                   & \ldot & \ldot & \sdot & \sdot \\
         \begin{tabenum}[resume*=tab]\item Minimise the number of different types of material Minimise the number of different types of material Minimise the number of different types of material\end{tabenum}                      & \ldot & TEXT & \sdot & text \\
\begin{tabenum}[resume*=tab]\item Use recycled and recyclable materials \end{tabenum} & \ldot & \ldot & \sdot & \sdot \\
\begin{tabenum}[resume*=tab]\item Minimise the number of different types of material                         \end{tabenum} & \ldot & TEXT & \sdot & text \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```